# How can I draw table in markdown file?

Tags: markdown

I searched the paragraphs of estimated answer in [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables)

> Tables aren't part of the core Markdown spec, but they are part of
>   GFM and Markdown Here supports them. They are an easy way of adding
>   tables to your email -- a task that would otherwise require
>   copy-pasting from another application.

But How can I change for my markdown to support the GFM?

Comment: Is this question related to the Markdown Here browser extension? If not, please specify how you're parsing your markdown.

Comment: Ok. it is not related to the that. I am using markdownPad 2 application in local and I will upload this to the gitlab for readme.

Comment: All right. It seems you'll need to buy the pro version in order to get support for GFM and tables. http://markdownpad.com/compare.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you are using your Markdown but there isn't a metadata which indicate the flavor of Markdown who will be used. It is the parser of the Markdown text who indicates the features who will be available in the file.

In short, if you want to use the possibilities of GFM, you need to use a parser capable to parse GFM.

Comment: So I find the parser for GFM?

Comment: After seeing your comments above, you can try to edit the file directly with the Markdown here extension and then commit it to the gitlab repository where normally the table should appear as expected. https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/markdown/markdown.md